# HTML email with Outlook 2013 - border-left and td alignment issue

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm working on an html email signature and am pulling my hair out trying to get it to work with outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013. In every other email client it looks just as I want it to. Here's what I'm going for:

[image: intended email signature]

Here's what I'm seeing in Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013:

[image: email signature in outlook]

The second cell alignment is off and the left border on the table isn't visible. Can any figure out what I'm doing wrong based on my code pasted below? Thanks so much in advance!

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

<table style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-left:-8px;border-left: 7px solid #9d2235;" width="100%" cellpadding="15px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="100px" bgcolor="#e5e5e5" style="border: 3px solid #e5e5e5;vertical-align: top;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;">
                <a href="https://canada.ntm.org"><img src="https://canada.ntm.org/files/email-sig-files/NTMC%20Logo%20red.png" alt="NTMC Canada" width="100" height="46" /></a>
            </td>
            <td  bgcolor="#e5e5e5" style="border: 3px solid #e5e5e5;text-align:left;color:#333;font-family:'Helvetica Neue','HelveticaNeue',Helvetica,Arial,'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;font-weight: 300;vertical-align: top;font-size:14px;padding-bottom:7px;padding-top:7px">
                <strong>Norm Copeland</strong><br>
                <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#333" href="mailto:norm_copeland@ntm.org">norm_copeland@ntm.org</a><br>
                844-855-6862 x213<br>
                <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#9d2235" href="https://canada.ntm.org">canada.ntm.org</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.[Outlook does not support margin](https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/outlookcom-margins/).

2.[Use 600px for the width of table](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/width/).

[Fixed link](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/c21b1yth/)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            *
            {
                padding:0px;
                margin:0px;
                font-family:'Helvetica Neue','HelveticaNeue',Helvetica,Arial,'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;
            }

            a
            {
                text-decoration:none;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Outlook</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table style="margin: 0 auto;" width="600px" height="85px" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" border="0" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="7px" bgcolor="#9d2235"></td>
                    <td width="160px" bgcolor="#e5e5e5" style="text-align:center;">
                        <a href="https://canada.ntm.org"><img src="https://canada.ntm.org/files/email-sig-files/NTMC%20Logo%20red.png" alt="NTMC Canada" width="100" height="46" /></a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="433px" bgcolor="#e5e5e5" style="text-align:left;color:#333;font-weight: 300;font-size:14px;">
                        <strong>Norm Copeland</strong><br>
                        <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#333" href="mailto:norm_copeland@ntm.org">norm_copeland@ntm.org</a><br>
                        844-855-6862 x213<br>
                        <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#9d2235" href="https://canada.ntm.org">canada.ntm.org</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alireza. I ran a test using litmus and Outlook 2013 still isn't right. See screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/060g1B2I3H3Q. I also will need to leave the css inline as I'm just wanting to give out the email signature to my co-workers.

Comment: @Normc I'm sorry to reply late, I checked it out in outlook(hotmail.com), [it worked](http://s22.postimg.org/r70dyacox/Capture.png). 1-Save the html file. 2-Open it in browser. 3-Select all(not in view source, I mean the web view) and copy. 4-Finally, paste it outlook.